# Plot multiple solutions for different t terms

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions

I want to integrate a a simple function for different `t` values.

At the moment I have the following code;

```
t = 2;
y[x_] = x^t;
SetAttributes[y , Listable]

yy = Integrate[y[x], x]
ListPlot[Table[{x,yy}, {x,0,10}]]
```

How could I return at once the `yy` solutions, but with different `t` terms and plot the multiple `yy` solutions for different `t` terms all in one graph?

Also I would like to use this solutions in later functions. How could I pass on solutions for multiple `t` values to ensure in future that functions using the solutions would be able to access the solution for any `t` value?

I am new to mathematica not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could I return at once the yy solutions but for different t terms and
>   plot multiple yy solutions for different t terms all in one graph?

One way could be to change the definition of your `y` to also accept `t`. Something like

```
ClearAll[y, t, x]
y[x_, t_] = x^t;
tValues = Range[4];
yy = Table[Callout[Integrate[y[x, t], x], Row[{"t =", t}]], {t, tValues}];
Plot[Evaluate@yy, {x, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"},BaseStyle -> 12,
     GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that has the advantage that you are not committed to the independent variable being `x`.

```
SetAttributes[y, Listable]
y[t_] = #^t &;
SetAttributes[yInt, Listable]
yInt[t_] = Integrate[y[t][#], #] &;
```

Then you can plot `yInt` multiple values of `t` with

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Through[yInt[Range[4]][x]], {x, 0, 2}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: plot]

You can map `yInt` over  a range in the usual way.

```
yInt[#][x] & /@ Range[-4, 4]
```

> `{-(1/(3 x^3)), -(1/(2 x^2)), -(1/x), Log[x], x, x^2/2, x^3/3, x^4/4, x^5/5}`

Or do it with `Through` making use of it `Listable` attribute.

```
Through[yInt[Range[-4, 4]][u]]
```

> `{-(1/(3 x^3)), -(1/(2 x^2)), -(1/x), Log[x], x, x^2/2, x^3/3, x^4/4, x^5/5}`

And, of course, call from other functions.

```
Integrate[yInt[1/2][z], z]
```

> `(4 z^(5/2))/15`